# Sign_and_send_pubkey: no mutual signature supported

Tags: ssh, openssh

I tried to connect to ssh server in M1 macOS terminal like this

```
ssh -i {myKeyFilePath/myKeyFile.pem} user@host
```

but it returns

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: no mutual signature supported
user@host: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I didn't modify any ssh settings, and the file permissions of {myKeyFile.pem} is 400.
Also I can connect ssh server well by IntelliJ remote hosts,
but when I tried this in terminal, it goes wrong.

Comment: Definitely happened to me when I upgraded to macOS Ventura, thanks for the question!

Comment: There is a bug against OpenSSH where people

Comment: @LHMathies - Not a bug. ssh-rsa is deprecated. I wrote an article on the technical reasons: https://www.jhanley.com/blog/ssh-signature-algorithm-ssh-rsa-error/

Answer (score 288, accepted):

When I updated my Mac system, all the ssh server can't ssh with the private key, you can add the 3 lines below in the beginning of your ~/.ssh/config.

But the best solution is create a new private key and upload the public key to  each server one by one, because when you got this error, means your private key is deprecated to use.

```
# vim ~/.ssh/config, add the lines at the beginning
Host *
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
    HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
```

Comment: There is a good security reason that `ssh-rsa` was disabled. Choosing this method is not recommended and should be the **last resort**.

Comment: @JohnHanley I just spent 3 hours trying to figure out what is going on after update to Mac Ventura, this answer helped. What is the good reasons for the fact that it was disabled? thank you

Comment: This worked for us after updating to macOS Ventura. Thanks!

`PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa` by itself did NOT do the trick. The `HostKeyAlgorithms` was also necessary.

Comment: @Eugene - The reason is that SHA1 has been considered unsafe since 2016 and should not be used. https://www.computerworld.com/article/3173616/the-sha1-hash-function-is-now-completely-unsafe.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure the config path is `/etc/ssh/config`, not `/etc/.ssh/config`.

Comment: Looks like we all run into this issue after upgrade macOS to **Ventura**. Plus what @JohnHanley said, I guess **Ventura** has disabled the `ssh-rsa` by default. That's why we can't ssh to the most servers we were able to ssh to. 
 Another fun fact is `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` now is an alias of `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms`, I can't even find the former one in the man page.

Comment: Check if your server ssh version is old. My client ssh was new - 9.0 with the MacOS Ventura upgrade. Try running `ssh -V` on the server. Signature type `ssh-rsa` (sha1) has been non-supported since OpenSSH 8.8 and is replaced with `rsa-sha2-256` or `rsa-sha2-512` (added in OpenSSH 7.2 in 2016). So until the server is upgraded, the client will need the deprecated `ssh-rsa` flagged as permitted using PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes. Sources: https://superuser.com/questions/1734086/how-to-ssh-from-macos-terminal-to-ubuntu-22-04-no-matching-host-key-type-found https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.2

Comment: Instead of * you could specify the host by IP address or domain name of the server you want to connect to in order to restrict it.

Comment: After days of not being able to access my old servers after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04 this answer saved my week. Thank you!

Answer (score 64):

I spent a few hours until I came to this question and answers. Here is a quick try to `ssh` into the server and then deal with the stuff later:

```
ssh -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=ssh-rsa -i {yourfile} user@host
```

This combines the previous answers by **shoaly** and **John Hanley** which contain more details and suggestions worth to follow to.

Answer (score 50):

Most likely your SSH client is using `ssh-rsa` (RSA+SHA1) and your server has that signature algorithm disabled. SHA-1 is vulnerable and OpenSSH disabled that signature algorithm in version 8.8 (2021-09-26).

The replacement for ssh-rsa is rsa-sha2-256 and rsa-sha2-512.

Try this command:

```
ssh -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=rsa-sha2-256 -i {myKeyFilePath/myKeyFile.pem} user@host
```

If that command fails with an error regarding an unsupported key exchange, then your SSH client is probably ancient.

Use one of the following solutions:

- update the SSH client (usually a good idea)
- use a different SSH Key Type such as Ed25519 (recommended)
- enable rsa-sha in the SSH server (not recommended)

**Edit:**

If that works, you can permanently add it to your `~/.ssh/config` file, and eliminate it from the command line use. However, there is a valid security reason that rsa-sha1 was disabled. Only do this as a last resort because SHA1 has been broken. Do not enable rsa-sha1 if your servers are audited for security or exposed to the public Internet.

```
Host *
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

Replace `*` with a specific host or IP address to limit the use of this configuration.

Comment: I'd tried PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa and it worked! Thank you for your answer

Comment: You can also add this to `~/.ssh/config`. I'll edit the answer to show that part.

Comment: @TimShadel - If the SSH server has `rsa-sha1` disabled, adding something to `~/ssh/config` will accomplish nothing. In that case, the client must support `rsa-sha2`, which can be configured in `~/.shh/config`.

Comment: @JohnHanley this accepted answer involves adding parameters at the command line. Anything that you can add at the command line can go into SSH config. I think your contention is probably with the answer itself. The thing is, the answer actually works. This is especially important for individuals using macOS. There’s a version of SSH client that has a bug that doesn’t offer this option to the server, and that’s the one that got shipped with macOS.

Comment: Oops. I see that your question is about the _content_ of the confit (ssh-rsa vs rsa-sha2-256). My reasoning still stands, though. macOS shipped with a bug that has been fixed in a recent version, but that has not been picked up by macOS 13.0.1, so until then we need to use this method to connect to servers that haven’t changed at all.

Comment: With my Godaddy server running`OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013` it seems like my Mac OS 10.16's  old `OpenSSH_8.1p1,` continues to be passwordless with rsa, but my new Ubuntu 22's `OpenSSH_8.9p1` doesn't allow me to get away with it. I don't have a solution for passwordless login sadly.

Answer (score 10):

I had this message for a lot of time on AWS EC2 trying to connect with ssh:

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: no mutual signature supported
```

the code above save me:

```
# vim ~/.ssh/config, add the lines at the beginning
Host *
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
    HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
```

Answer (score 2):

After the Mac system is upgraded to Ventura 13.1, I encounter the problem that SSH is configured with passwordless login, but the password is still required, my solution is to upgrade and encrypt the server's key to ed25519:

```
// 1. server: check HostKey in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
...
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

// 2. client: ssh-keygen -t ed25519
ssh-keygen -t ed25519

// 3. client: vim ~/.ssh/ssh_config
Host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

// 4. client: ssh-copy-id 
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub

// 5. test ssh using identity file
ssh -v username@hostname
```

more about see `man sshd_config`, search keywords `HostKey` and `HostKeyAlgorithms`

```
 HostKey
    Specifies a file containing a private host key used by SSH.  The defaults are /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key,
    /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key and /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.

    Note that sshd(8) will refuse to use a file if it is group/world-accessible and that the HostKeyAlgorithms
    option restricts which of the keys are actually used by sshd(8).
HostKeyAlgorithms
    Specifies the host key signature algorithms that the server offers.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an updated security setting intended to push you toward a more secure algorithm. If you can upload a new key to your target host, you might as well make a new key using [current best practices](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/144044):

```bash
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -a 100
```

You'll then want to upload the public key `~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub` to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on my local pc and this error was not happening but when I deployed to the client (customer) 's server thats when I got this error.

Let me guide you on what helped.

First of all find out the version of ssh client you're using:

```
ssh -V
```

On my local PC I get `OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3` but on client's server I get `OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.2p1, LibreSSL 3.7.2`

Now, when I connect to the remote ssh server, I use below command:

```
sftp  -i  ./files/keys/my_private_key.id_rsa -P 8092 GIL@1.1.1.1
```

From my PC I connect without any error, but on the customer's server I get this error:

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: no mutual signature supported
GIL@1.1.1.1: Permission denied (publickey).
Connection closed
```

I also noticed that I get this error when I try to connect to ssh server from my local pc using the git bash and the above sftp connection command:

```
GIL@1.1.1.1: Permission denied (publickey).
Connection closed
Connection closed.
```

Now to fix this, from the customer's server, I opened the config file located at `C:\Users\GIL\.ssh\config` and added below two lines:

```
Host *
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

Now it works. I DID NOT restart OpenSSH server running on the customer's PC. However, I did have another program implemented using nodejs, I had to restart it for it to connect to the remote ssh server.

Another thing I didnt experiment with was installing a lower version of OpenSSH server on the customer's PC.